# duplicates tables mysql show tables (Azure Instance)

Tags: mysql, azure

We have connected with our live database ,
When running `show tables` command with database,

Found few tables are duplicate

Ex - Table Names

```
 bookings
 bookings
```

Mysql Version - "5.7.32-log"

Please assist what could be reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Microsoft expert has already responded to everyone [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/345201/view.html), this issue was caused by a bug which was mitigated with a hotfix, users needs to restart Azure Database for MySQL server for the hotfix to take affect. Users may restart the server using instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/howto-restart-server-portal).